# convert Image Data to Byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, byte

I have to get imageData from Database in the form of byte[]. I think i am doing everything right but converting the data to byte[](at the underlined part of code) makes me frustrated. Could someone please help? This is an AsP.net application.

```
public byte[] getDIImages(int DIImageID)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
            {
                  new SqlParameter("@DIImageID",DIImageID )
            };

            string commandText = "SELECT ImageData, ImageName FROM [DI_Image] WHERE DIImageID =@DI_ImageID";
            DataSet pds = new DataSet();
            SqlHelper.FillDataset(DbConnString, System.Data.CommandType.Text, commandText, pds, new string[] { "ImageInfo" }, parameters);
           # ***Convert.ToByte(pds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageData"]);
            return byte1;*** #

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError("Error Occurred When Getting Images : " + PageID.ToString());
            return new byte[1];
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What format is it stored in the database? Byte[]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data should already be a `byte[]`:

```
return (byte[])pds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageData"];
```